# How to convert a timedelta object into a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

What is the proper way to convert a timedelta object into a datetime object?

I immediately think of something like `datetime(0)+deltaObj`, but that's not very nice... Isn't there a `toDateTime()` function or something of the sort?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to convert a timedelta into a datetime, but it does make sense to pick an initial or starting datetime and add or subtract a timedelta from that.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 9, 18, 25, 19, 474362)
>>> today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 10, 18, 25, 19, 474362)
```

Comment: +1: Epochal dates.  March 8th is my daughter's birthday, that's a better epochal date than March 9th.  Unix folks like Jan 1, 1970.  Don't know why, that's not my daughter's birthday.

Comment: I am trying to do this: `period['start_date'] = (self.start_date + timedelta(days=roundtrip_component.day-1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`, and I get this error: `TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta`. So I guess in this case it makes sense to change the type **timedelta** to **date**

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to convert it I have  StartTime and EndTime of trips which are both in time delta format and I am trying to figure out why and how to put them in time format. On the phpmyadmin is normal time and when I download it from a tunnel and use it in python, they are both timedelta and I can not do anything with them

Comment: Not helpful.  Do not redefine a question and then answer it.  I have a timedelta I need to get into a datetime so I can format it.

Answer (score 2):

Since a datetime represents a time within a single day, your timedelta should be less than 24 hours (86400 seconds), even though timedeltas are not subject to this constraint.

```
import datetime

seconds = 86399
td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
print(td)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(td), "%H:%M:%S")
print(dt)

23:59:59
1900-01-01 23:59:59
```

If you don't want a default date and know the date of your timedelta:

```
date = "05/15/2020"
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(date, td), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(dt2)

2020-05-15 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I could take the .total_seconds() and use that to create a new time object (or datetime object if needed).

```py
import time
import datetime

start_dt_obj = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(start_timestamp)
stop_dt_obj = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stop_timestamp)
delta = stop_dt_obj - start_dt_obj

delta_as_time_obj = time.gmtime(delta.total_seconds())
```

This allows you to do something like:

```py
print('The duration was {0}'.format(
    time.strftime('%H:%M', delta_as_time_obj)
)
```

Comment: that's a time object not a datetime object ( as asked )

Answer (score 1):

I share your pain bro

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Both variables datetime
birthday = datetime.datetime(2000, 5, 24)
today = datetime.datetime.today()

# Time you've been alive in timedelta format
time_alive = today - birthday
print(time_alive)
>>> 8609 days, 18:47:53.341251

# Get only the time to concatenate later
hours = (datetime.datetime.min + time_alive).time()
print(hours)
>>> 18:47:53.341251

# Date that you've been alive
age = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.fromordinal(time_alive.days) - relativedelta(years=1), hours)
print(age)
>>> 0023-07-27 18:47:53.341251
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import datetime`enter code here
    lastDownloadedDate = datetime.date(2022,8,4)
    print('lastDownloadedDate: ', lastDownloadedDate)
    fdate = lastDownloadedDate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    fdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(fdate), "%Y-%m-%d")
    fdate = datetime.date(fdate.year, fdate.month, fdate.day)
    print('fdate: ', dt3)`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Improving @sadpanduar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59278188/11671779) with example on converting one column in `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
import time

def seconds_to_datetime(seconds, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):
    td = timedelta(seconds=seconds)
    time_obj = time.gmtime(td.total_seconds())
    return time.strftime(format, time_obj)
```

```py
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH)
df['TIMESTAMP_COLUMN'] = df['TIMESTAMP_COLUMN'].apply(seconds_to_datetime)
```