# timedelta to string type in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe `df` and its first column is `timedelta64`

```
df.info():

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 686 entries, 0 to 685
Data columns (total 6 columns):
0    686 non-null timedelta64[ns]
1    686 non-null object
2    686 non-null object
3    686 non-null object
4    686 non-null object
5    686 non-null object
```

If I `print(df[0][2])`, for example, it will give me `0 days 05:01:11`. However, I don't want the `0 days` filed. I only want `05:01:11` to be printed. Could someone teaches me how to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: any preference for the data type of the resulting column?

Comment: object type would be fine for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible by:

```
df['duration1'] = df['duration'].astype(str).str[-18:-10]
```

But solution is not general, if input is `3 days 05:01:11` it remove `3 days` too.

So solution working only for timedeltas less as one day correctly.

More general solution is [create custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539360):

```
N = 10
np.random.seed(11230)
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 15:30:00', periods=N, freq='13.5H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': np.abs(np.random.choice(rng, size=N) - 
                                 np.random.choice(rng, size=N)) })  

df['duration1'] = df['duration'].astype(str).str[-18:-10]

def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

df['duration2'] = df['duration'].apply(f)
print (df)

         duration duration1  duration2
0 2 days 06:00:00  06:00:00   54:00:00
1 2 days 19:30:00  19:30:00   67:30:00
2 1 days 03:00:00  03:00:00   27:00:00
3 0 days 00:00:00  00:00:00    0:00:00
4 4 days 12:00:00  12:00:00  108:00:00
5 1 days 03:00:00  03:00:00   27:00:00
6 0 days 13:30:00  13:30:00   13:30:00
7 1 days 16:30:00  16:30:00   40:30:00
8 0 days 00:00:00  00:00:00    0:00:00
9 1 days 16:30:00  16:30:00   40:30:00
```

Comment: how to do it if we don't know the name of the columns? like when we create pivot table

Comment: @cikatomo do you need apply for all columns? then use `df = df.applymap(f)`

Comment: actually all except one. Does `applymap` include index?

Comment: @cikatomo - no, for `TimedeltaIindex` need `rename` like `df = df.rename(index = f)`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a short and robust version using `apply()`:

```
df['timediff_string'] = df['timediff'].apply(
    lambda x: f'{x.components.hours:02d}:{x.components.minutes:02d}:{x.components.seconds:02d}'
              if not pd.isnull(x) else ''
)
```

This leverages the *components* attribute of pandas Timedelta objects and also handles empty values (NaT).

If the *timediff* column does not contain pandas Timedelta objects, you can convert it:

```
df['timediff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['timediff'])
```

Answer (score 3):

`datetime.timedelta` already formats the way you'd like. The crux of this issue is that Pandas internally converts to `numpy.timedelta`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

time_1 = timedelta(days=3, seconds=3400)
time_2 = timedelta(days=0, seconds=3400)
print(time_1)
print(time_2)

times = pd.Series([time_1, time_2])

# Times are converted to Numpy timedeltas.
print(times)

# Convert to string after converting to datetime.timedelta.
times = times.apply(
    lambda numpy_td: str(timedelta(seconds=numpy_td.total_seconds())))

print(times)
```

So, convert to a `datetime.timedelta` and then `str` (to prevent conversion back to `numpy.timedelta`) before printing.

```
3 days, 0:56:40
0:56:400

0   3 days 00:56:40
1   0 days 00:56:40
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

0    3 days, 0:56:40
1            0:56:40
dtype: object
```

I came here looking for answers to the same question, so I felt I should add further clarification. : )

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it into a [Python `timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), then to `str` and finally back to a `Series`:

```
pd.Series(df["duration"].dt.to_pytimedelta().astype(str), name="start_time")
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'. Is this answer up to date?

Comment: Seems like your `df["duration"]` object is not a `pd.Series` but a `Timedelta`? If it's a `pd.Series`, it should have `dt`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_pytimedelta.html

Answer (score 1):

Given OP is ok with an object column (a little verbose):

```
def splitter(td):

  td = str(td).split(' ')[-1:][0]

  return td


df['split'] = df['timediff'].apply(splitter)
```

Basically we're taking the timedelta column, transforming the contents to a string, then splitting the string (creates a list) and taking the last item of that list, which would be the hh:mm:ss component.

Note that specifying `' '` for what to split by is redundant here.

Alternative one liner:

```
df['split2'] = df['timediff'].astype('str').str.split().str[-1]
```

which is very similar, but not very pretty IMHO. Also, the output includes milliseconds, which is not the case in the first solution. I'm not sure what the reason for that is (please comment if you do). If your data is big it might be worthwhile to time these different approaches.

Comment: Thanks! I think once convert the type to str, then everything is relatively easy by using split.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure that your timedelta is less than a day, this might work. To do this in as few lines as possible, I [convert the timedelta to a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2413400/1486966) by adding the unix epoch 0 and then using the [now-datetime dt function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742330/1486966) to format the date format.

```py
df['duration1'] = (df['duration'] + pd.to_datetime(0)).dt.strftime('%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

If wou want to remove all nonzero components (not only days), you can do it like this:

```
def pd_td_fmt(td):
    import pandas as pd
    abbr = {'days': 'd', 'hours': 'h', 'minutes': 'min', 'seconds': 's', 'milliseconds': 'ms', 'microseconds': 'us',
        'nanoseconds': 'ns'}

    fmt = lambda td:"".join(f"{v}{abbr[k]}" for k, v in td.components._asdict().items() if v != 0)
    if isinstance(td, pd.Timedelta):
        return fmt(td)
    elif isinstance(td,pd.TimedeltaIndex):
        return td.map(fmt)
    else:
        raise ValueError
```