# Adding time duration (as int) to time (as object)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data frame:

```
     date time_start  duration_seconds
 10-01-18   12:56:52              1382
 10-01-18   12:56:52               164
 10-01-18   23:56:00               250
```

The dtypes are:

```
date                datetime64[ns]
time_start                  object
duration_seconds             int64
```

I want to add the `duration_seconds` to `time_start` and create `time_end` column.
Also, to concatenate `time` & `date`, for the start- and end- time.

Expected result:

```
     date time_start  duration_seconds  time_end time_start_with_date time_end_with_date
 10-01-18   12:56:52              1382  13:19:54    10-01-18 12:56:52  10-01-18 13:19:54
 10-01-18   12:56:52               164  12:59:36    10-01-18 12:56:52  10-01-18 12:59:36
 10-01-18   23:56:00               250  00:00:10    10-01-18 23:56:00  11-01-18 00:00:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create `datetime` column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and the sum columns:

```
df['time_start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_start'])
df['time_end'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration_seconds'], unit='s') + df['time_start']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%y')

df['time_start_with_date'] = df['date'] + df['time_start']
df['time_end_with_date'] = df['date'] + df['time_end']
print (df)
        date time_start  duration_seconds        time_end  \
0 2018-01-10   12:56:52              1382 0 days 13:19:54   
1 2018-01-10   12:56:52               164 0 days 12:59:36   
2 2018-01-10   23:56:00               250 1 days 00:00:10   

  time_start_with_date  time_end_with_date  
0  2018-01-10 12:56:52 2018-01-10 13:19:54  
1  2018-01-10 12:56:52 2018-01-10 12:59:36  
2  2018-01-10 23:56:00 2018-01-11 00:00:10
```

For custom format of datetimes:

```
df['time_start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_start'])
df['time_end'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration_seconds'], unit='s') + df['time_start']
date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%y')

df['time_start_with_date'] = (date + df['time_start']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
df['time_end_with_date'] = (date + df['time_end']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/51102096/2901002
#solution convert only HH:MM:SS to strings, removed all days
df['time_start'] = df['time_start'].astype(str).astype(str).str[-18:-10]
df['time_end'] = df['time_end'].astype(str).astype(str).str[-18:-10]
print (df)
       date time_start  duration_seconds  time_end time_start_with_date  \
0  10-01-18   12:56:52              1382  13:19:54    10-01-18 12:56:52   
1  10-01-18   12:56:52               164  12:59:36    10-01-18 12:56:52   
2  10-01-18   23:56:00               250  00:00:10    10-01-18 23:56:00   

  time_end_with_date  
0  10-01-18 13:19:54  
1  10-01-18 12:59:36  
2  11-01-18 00:00:10
```

Comment: Thanks. `time end` could be `13:19:54` and not `0 days 13:19:54`?

Comment: @qwerty - Formating of timedeltas not easy, please give me some time.