# print elements in TimedeltaIndex

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I have a TimedeltaIndex named `durations`

```
print(durations)

TimedeltaIndex(['05:00:00', '11:15:00', '07:30:00'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Is it possible just to print each element of the TimedeltaIndex individually?

For example if I print `durations[0]` this will output:
`Timedelta('0 days 05:00:00')`

What would I need to print just `05:00:00` without any associated Timedelta information?

**EDIT**
possible solution? Create empty list..

```
stuff = []
stuff = durations.index.astype(str).str[-8:-3]
```

Now it seems like I can print each element of the list:

```
stuff[0]
stuff[1]
```

returns:

```
'00:00'
'05:00'
```

Comment: So it's a little ambiguous. `timedelta` can store any unit of time; that display is only valid when you have times between `[0, 24Hours)`. Once you add a large timedelta like '25:01:15'` the display now shows as `'0 days 05:00:00'` for all of the timedeltas. The same issue arises with negative timedeltas... It's really difficult to know how to handle these cases.

Comment: There's are numerous proposed solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string. Many of the highly voted ones will fail with large or negative timedeltas so read carefully

Comment: I made an edit to the post, does this seem like a wonky way of creating a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to separate the different parts of the output and only choose the third item like below:

```
print(str(durations[0]).split(' ')[2])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: Try just `durations[0].seconds.apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(seconds=x))
`

Comment: Thanks for the help, its still giving me an error. `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Comment: dumb question can `durations[0]` be converted to a different data type like a float/string or something like that?

Comment: I think the solution is here somewhere... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101432/timedelta-to-string-type-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Happy to help :)