# pandas multiply column by minutes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column df['Rounds'] that is int64 and the values can be 1-5.

I need to calculate the fight duration `((df[Rounds]-1)*(00:05:00))+df['final_round_duration']`

but this did not work.

numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')

| Rounds | final_round_duration | fight_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:03:00 | 00:03:00 |
| 3 | 00:02:00 | 00:12:00 |
| 5 | 00:05:00 | 00:25:00 |

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: updated with the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by a [pd.Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas-timedelta) instead:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Rounds': [1, 3, 5],
                   'final_round_duration': ['00:03:00', '00:02:00', '00:05:00']})

# Calculate Duration Time
df['flight_duration'] = (df['Rounds'] - 1) * pd.Timedelta(minutes=5) + \
                        pd.to_timedelta(df['final_round_duration'])

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
Rounds final_round_duration flight_duration
     1             00:03:00 0 days 00:03:00
     3             00:02:00 0 days 00:12:00
     5             00:05:00 0 days 00:25:00
```

---

Timedeltas can be reformatted back to just hours, minutes, and seconds

(See. [timedelta to string type in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51101432/15497888))

```py
import pandas as pd


def format_timedelta(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return f'{int(hours)}:{int(minutes):02d}:{ int(seconds):02d}'


df = pd.DataFrame({'Rounds': [1, 3, 5],
                   'final_round_duration': ['00:03:00', '00:02:00', '00:05:00']})

# Calculate Duration Time
df['flight_duration'] = (
        (df['Rounds'] - 1)
        * pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
        + pd.to_timedelta(df['final_round_duration'])
).apply(format_timedelta) # Apply Formatting

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
Rounds final_round_duration flight_duration
     1             00:03:00         0:03:00
     3             00:02:00         0:12:00
     5             00:05:00         0:25:00
```