# select TIME Type from mysql to python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a mysql table that includes columns of type TIME. When I try to read the value in Python, normally used in mysql.connector, I would expect to get value of data type datetime.time() or a similar type that refers to a time that does not include a date. Instead I get data of type datetime.timedelta(). Is there a simple way to convert the data to a more appropriate type?

Comment: Please attach a reproducible example of your code and the query you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a timedelta object into a datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413391/how-to-convert-a-timedelta-object-into-a-datetime-object)